# Is it possible to ignore the trailing return type feature of c++11 in favor of the function return type deduction feature of c++14?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, trailing-return-type, return-type-deduction

### When I skip the return type of an expression

The following code in **C++11**:

```
auto function(X x, Y y) -> decltype(x + y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

Is equal to the following code in **C++14**:

```
decltype(auto) function(X x, Y y)
{
    return x + y;
}
```

But additionally it is possible to deduce the return type without `decltype` rules in **C++14**:

```
auto function()
{
    return 0;
}
```

### When I know what the return type is exactly

The following code in **C++11**:

```
auto function() -> int
{
    return 0;
}
```

Is equal to the following code in **C++03**:

```
int function()
{
    return 0;
}
```

### A strange example that should never happen

The following code in **C++11**:

```
auto function(X x, Y y) -> decltype(x * y)
{
    return x; // Yeah! return x with the type of x * y expression!
}
```

Is equal to the following code in **C++14**:

```
decltype(auto) function(X x, Y y)
{
    return static_cast<decltype(x * y)>(x);
}
```

Please correct me, if the above code is wrong and does not work as expected.

**EDIT**, *According to the comment (Yakk): They are not really equal, the first one (**C++11** example) is an implicit cast while the second one (the `static_cast` of **C++14** example) is an explicit cast.*

### Conclusion

As you can see, I can do everything without using the *alternative function syntax* feature of C++11. Am I correct? Can I completely forget about it without getting any technical problem?

In general, the following syntax can be avoided:

```
auto function() -> TYPE
{
    return 0;
}
```

In favor of the following syntax:

```
TYPE function() // TYPE can be: auto, decltype(auto), or ...
{
    return 0;
}
```

Did I forget any usage of the *trailing return type* feature of C++11 that is not possible with the *function return type deduction* feature of C++14?

Comment: SFINAE!!? i didn't hear about it! and should search it now :-D

Comment: `static_cast` is not an implicit cast.  It can be stronger.  As an example, if `x*y` returns type `Q*`, and `X` if of type `U*`, and `Q` is a derived class of `U`, then `auto function(X x, Y y) -> decltype(x*y) { return x; }` is different than `auto function( X x, Y y ) { return static_cast<decltype(x*y)>(x); }` -- one compiles, the other does not.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are three important differences between a function using automatic-return-type-deduction and one with an explicit return-type (even if that is computed):

1. You cannot do SFINAE on the computability of the return-type if you do not explicitly specify it: You get a hard error instead. Why? Because SFINAE only works with the declaration, not the definition of functions (SFINAE: (template-argument) substitution-failure is not an error).

   [automatic-return-type-deduction](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fa14fbaa17e62543), no SFINAE
   [SFINAE](//coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99e8747a42bde63e), but no automatic return-type deduction

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   int doit(int x, ...) { return x; }
   template<class X, class Y> auto doit(X x, Y y)
   #ifdef TRAILING_RETURN_TYPE
   -> decltype(doit(x) + doit(y))
   #endif
   { return doit(x) + doit(y); }

   int main() {
       std::cout << doit(1, nullptr) << "\n";
   }
   ```
2. At the moment, you cannot forward-declare a function with its actual return-type, if the definition uses automatic return-type-deduction, nor can it be virtual. (Explicit rule)

   > #### 7.1.6.4 auto specifier `[dcl.spec.auto]`
   >
   > 13 Redeclarations or specializations of a function or function template with a declared return type that uses a placeholder type shall also use that placeholder, not a deduced type.
   > 14 A function declared with a return type that uses a placeholder type shall not be virtual (10.3).
3. Only functions with automatic return-type deduction can return a lambda, as there is no other way to get its type.

   ```
    auto foo() { return [] {}; }
   ```

Link to the proposal, which was incorporated into the draft for C++14:
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3638.html

Comment: nice improvement =D (duplicates help sometimes)

Comment: @pepper_chico Yes, they help ;-)